# No red error bar in the review queue

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed

When I'm on the review queues, sometimes I can't edit the post for various reasons. (I have a maxed out edit queue, or someone else's edit is pending).

When this happens on the normal site, a red bar will appear to explain the reason I can't edit, but when I'm in the queue, there's no bar.

This is a bug, I believe, and I think it should be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This [has been fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380969/4751173) on March 6th, 2019:

> Starting with the next build, we'll be showing an error message same way as we do on regular question pages:
>
> > [image]

See also [this Meta Stack Exchange thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298797/editing-a-post-during-review-doesnt-show-an-edit-not-possible-message).